# JUnit 5 vintage engine for JUnit 4 error: Unsupported version of junit:junit: 4.11. Please upgrade to version 4.12 or later. How to downgrade?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit-vintage

```java
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Unsupported version of junit:junit: 4.11. Please upgrade to version 4.12 or later.
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:49)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:35)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:62)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
    ... 7 more
```

When I use JUnit 5 with vintage engine, this error appears. The aim was to:

- attempt to move to JUnit 5 gradually, without breaking existing JUnit 4 tests in one module of the whole, big project
- do not touch existing JUnit 4 dependency in my module

So, how do I know which version should I downgrade JUnit 5 to, in order to be compatible with JUnit 4.11? I now have 5.7.0.

Comment: Why do require JUnit 4.11, why can't you update to JUnit 4.12 (or 4.13.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you won't get JUnit 4.11 support with any downgrade version of JUnit 5 or JUnit vintage engine. JUnit vintage requires JUnit 4.12 or higher.

([source](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1264), among [others](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1944))